# Missing Trailing slash after domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, nginx

I have migrated magento code base from one machine to another, so web server configuration is different, I do not have access to working machine.

**Problem**

www.example.com has internal file load failures due to missing slash after domain name.

**Example of internally failing URLs**

www.example.comjs 
www.example.comcss

I have tried nginx and apace, both give same issue. I do not know how can i fix it. Please help for any server nginx or apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the stores DB using a MySQL viewer.
2. go to table name "core_config_data".
3. find record with name "unsecure_base_url" and another called "secure_base_url"
4. make sure the site is written in this format http://example.com/
5. make sure you have a slash after the domain name.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks @laith I had done that step but issue was with related to configuration of webserver, directory permission etc. I have accepted as answer thinking its right thing to check and it can help others.

Comment: Ok can you share your apache config?

Comment: you can also try getting a fresh copy of the .htaccess file and place it in your store.

Comment: Thanks @laith I had setup the server again, using official guide of magento and choosing the right version of softwares and it worked. Thanks a lot for help.